# Crash at inserting element at begin of STL deque

Tags: c++, stl, crash, embedded

On long run, I have noted crash on inserting element at begin of the STL deque (Double ended queues). This is the equivalent code snippet:

```
void func(std::deque<float> &list, float val)
{
  long curr_sz = list.size();
  if (curr_sz < 1)
  {
    list.insert(list.begin() + 0, val);
    return;
  }
}
```

Code is crashing at list.insert(list.begin() + 0, val). Crash is happening only on Edge device on long run. In PC version, it is not getting crash.
Please help me what can be the possible reason.

Comment: Your code inside the function could be simplified as `if (list.empty()) { list.emplace_front(val); }`

Comment: Please show a [mre] if this code is crashing then something else has probably corrupted `list` or your program is simply running out of memory

Answer (score 1):

The core problem seems to be the `+ 0`. You are adding to a deque interator. I would avoid doing that. Instead, use - as @SomeProgrammerdude mentioned in the comments - use `.emplace_front(val)` or `.push_front(val)`.
Also, instead of checking the size simply use `list.empty()`. If you want to use `size()` use `std::size_t`, not `long` to store the result. A `long` might overflow.